# Without Tags XML

Tags: r, xml, output

I wrote R code that prints XML file but I get an output with tags.
How do I display the output result without XML tag in R?

My R code :

```
library("XML")
library("methods")

dataxml = xmlParse(file = "PlayerData.xml")

print(dataxml)
```

my XML file :

```
<RECORD>
    <PLAYERS>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <PLAYTIME>4</PLAYTIME>
        <LEVEL>154</LEVEL>
    </PLAYERS>

    <PLAYERS>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <PLAYTIME>10</PLAYTIME>
        <LEVEL>200</LEVEL>
    </PLAYERS>

    <PLAYERS>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <PLAYTIME>9</PLAYTIME>
        <LEVEL>120</LEVEL>
    </PLAYERS>
</RECORD>
```

my expected result:

```
    ID  PLAYTIME  LEVEL
[1]  1         4    154
[2]  2        10    200
[3]  3         9    120
```

Comment: `print(xmlValue(dataxml))` ?

Comment: Your question would-be better if you also shared the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Since your XML is relatively flat in design, simply call the convenience method in XML package, `xmlToDataFrame`, to map content to an R data frame where tags become column headers and text become data values.

```r
library(XML)

dataxml <- xmlParse(file = "PlayerData.xml")

xml_df <_ xmlToDataFrame(dataxml)
xml_df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(dataxml, "//PLAYERS"))  # ALTERNATIVE

xml_df
#   ID PLAYTIME LEVEL
# 1  1        4   154
# 2  2       10   200
# 3  3        9   120
```